# How to find a piece of property on, say, Google Maps using Arizona's description?

Tags: united-states, plss

How to find a piece of property on, say, Google Maps, using Arizona's description:  `S2 SE4 NW4 SE4 SEC 5 16N 19 SAC`?

I found a different one described as:  `Section: 33 Township: 24N Range: 20W  GATEWAY ACRES TRACT 4 N2 LOT 21`. Or, I think I did.

These are descriptions on my Mohave County 2018 Property Tax Statement. Not sure, either, why they are described so differently. They are both in the middle of almost nowhere.

They were bought by my great grandmother who never let anyone know about them. My parents would like to learn about them and I'm pretty curious too.

Looking at the tags, I now realize this SE is meant for programming, but perhaps someone can point me to a place that explains their system. Or maybe it's a common system and someone knows right off how to read it?

Comment: Township/Range of the Public Land Survey System (PLSS) is more of a basic geography topic than a Geographic Information Systems one.  Any GIS package could do this, with the right data (note that Google Maps is **not** a GIS package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "SE4" is a necessary portion of a *PLSS aliquot part description*. Here's a link explaining such descriptions:

[https://www.ntc.blm.gov/krc/uploads/940/BLM_Module2_Studyguide.pd](https://www.ntc.blm.gov/krc/uploads/940/BLM_Module2_Studyguide.pdf)f

If you like a TL;DR version, here you go:

https://thediggings.com/faq/define-aliquot-part

Comment: Wow, strange. The two sets of addressing seem to be written from the inside out where, at least nowadays, one would think top down, all the way. Still, a very clear document. (Full version) The TL;DR one is as sad a thing as those usually get! I think this gets me about 98% of the way there. I will have to figure or find the Initial Point for the description, and it might be a tract within the township. Tracts seem to be arbitrary, like the described mining rights tracts, etc. And the Lots seem arbitrary as well... but maybe fit the non-aliquot idea in dividing Tracts?

Answer (score 0):

Contact the Mohave County Assessor's office.  They will have information about your specific parcel of interest, including its ownership history.